# How to retrieve contents of Summernote?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking for a smaller Javascript "editor" to use on my web projects. I found https://github.com/summernote/summernote/ and it looks nice and seems to hold some promise.

I tried using it by creating the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
    <script type="text/javascript"     src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- include summernote css/js-->
    <link href="assets/plugins/summernote-master/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/plugins/summernote-master/summernote.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>
<button onclick="getCode();return false;">Get the code!</button>
<script>
    function getCode()
    {
        var html = $("#summernote").summernote("code");
        console.log(html);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#summernote").summernote();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the documentation all you need to use is the `.summernote("code")` to gather the contents of the text editor window. However my Console.log results:

```
Object { length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → info.php, selector: "#summernote", 1 more… }  info.php:21:9
```

Does anyone have experience with this editor that could help me understand what I need to do differently? My goal is to gather the contents of the window as created by the user in a manner that I can POST to my application.

Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 4):

Change your HTML to the below.

```
<div class="summernote" id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>
```

Get the code!

and script to

```
<script>   

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".summernote").summernote();
});

function getCode()
{
    var html = $("#summernote").summernote("code");
    console.log(html);
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is the exact same as what's in the question, you just define the function later, I'm not sure how that's helpful.

Comment: HTML was not properly rendered. edited. check now. The code is tested and working fine.